# Solving linear system of equations using Successive Over-Relaxation

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I was solving a system of linear equations with SOR.  I used different values of relaxation factor (w) for the different runs.  I found that for all w > w' (1 < w' < 2), the error is the result dies down drastically.  Can someone please explain to me the reason for this?  I measured error against Inv(A)*B.

\begin{align}
A =\begin{pmatrix}
-2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & -2 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & -2 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix} &&
B=\begin{pmatrix}
1.012\\0.004\\
-0.004\\
-2.012
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you post the system?

Comment: @Amzoti Posted.

Comment: SOR is the same as the Gauss-Seidel-method, but with some relaxation factor $w$. You can change the $w$ in order to get faster convergence. The idea is the following: With every iteration method you get closer to the solution **step by step**. $w$ now changes the size of these steps, so the method converges faster. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Additionally, $A$ in your case is a sparse matrix, which reduces the amount of arithmetic operations. Due to faster convergence with bigger $w$, the amount of arithmetic operations will be reduced even more, which explains the smaller error for bigger $w$.

Comment: @fubel Thank you for the point in the 2nd para.  In my experiments, when w = 1.25, there is a huge drop in error when compared to w = 1.2 and it stays low for all w > 1.25.  I wanted to know if there is anything else causing huge drop in error.

Error at w = 1.2 is about 0.45 %
Error at w = 1.25 is 0.1 %

Is this just chance?

Comment: @codepk I think it might be by chance. Using the spectral radius I found out that the optimal $w$ should be $w=1.2596$. For this particular $w$ my solution is $x=[-0.4080,0.1960,0.8040,1.4080]^T$ for $k=13$ iterations. Do you get the same result?

Comment: @fubel Yes - bang on.  Sorry for the delay.